# Any reasons why AVQueuePlayer would sometimes work/sometimes not?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm creating a video player view where I download URLs from the Internet to play using an AVQueuePlayer. It generally works pretty fine except sometimes I'll get the play icon slashed out and the AVQueuePlayer breaks.

I'm not sure what triggers this broken AVQueuePlayer state.

I create new AVQueuePlayers on viewappear and on viewdisappear I run these lines on the player

ViewAppear

```
    if (self.player == nil){
        self.player = AVQueuePlayer()
    }
```

ViewDisappear

```
    self.player.pause()
    self.player.replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem(nil)
```

The main thing I'm curious of are there any potential reasons why a AVQueuePlayer will sometimes work and sometimes not? (It'll stop working after I trigger viewAppear, viewDisappear, viewAppear, etc. a few times)

Checking the network requests, when I do get the play button of death, no videos are streamed at all (0 network activity).

**Potential reasons:**

1)I'm thinking it might have something to do with the number of AVPlayers instantiated and I'm just not removing them correctly?

2) I also build the app on my phone a lot and close it while running it. Maybe this breaks the phone's avplayer over time?

Any directions for this type of behavior are appreciated.

EDIT: Interestingly enough, once in a while, it breaks so hard that I break every single app that plays video. Snapchat and Youtube don't work either after a certain point. I'm not sure how I broke every single player.

UPDATE: Getting this generic error for BOTH the AVPlayer & AVPlayerItem

```
Optional(Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11819 "Cannot Complete Action" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot Complete Action, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Try again later.})
```